# Centering vertically on equal height columns with Semantic UI

Tags: html, semantic-ui

I'm trying to layout a form using Semantic UI. Basically, I have 2 columns where I display the fields and buttons, like this:

[image: Semantic UI equal width columns]

The markup code is:
(NOTE: I've added borders to each column to help you see them. Also, I'm using Smarty templates)

```
  <div class="ui equal height container grid">
    <div class="ui row">
      <div class="ui ten wide column" style="border: 1px solid green">
        <!-- FORM -->
        {include file="form/left-column.tpl"}
      </div>

      <div class="ui six wide column" style="border: 1px solid blue">
        <div class="ui grid">
          <div class="ui sixteen wide middle aligned column" >
            <!-- BUTTONS -->
            {include file="form/right-column.tpl"}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The second column has a grid with a column with 'middle aligned' class, but it doesn't center the buttons in the middle. I've searched in the Semantic UI website docs but I couldn't find anything helpful for this. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What if you move the `middle aligned` classes from `.ui.column` to `.ui.grid`?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the delay, I had to swap to another project and I left this for a while. As you suggested, I tried to add the 'middle aligned' classes to the '.ui.grid' but the result is the same: it shrinks the column to the content's height. It centers the buttons, but what I want is both columns to have the same height to apply a background color and it looks awful if one of them is taller than the other.